# How to handle FileInputStream while using an InputStreamResource to return a file in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, garbage-collection

In an approach similar to the one given below to download a file using InputStreamResource, how can we ensure that there is no resource leak from the FileInputStream.

```
@GetMapping("/download")
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadFile() throws IOException {
  MediaType mediaType = MediaTypeUtils.getMediaTypeForFileName(this.servletContext, fileName);

  File file = new File(filePath);
  InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));

  return ResponseEntity.ok()
      .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + file.getName())
      .contentType(mediaType)
      .contentLength(file.length())
      .body(resource);
}
```

Will the GC always take care of the FileInputStream created from `new FileInputStream(file)` or is there a chance that leaks can occur. If so, then how to handle it?

Almost every approach I've tried to close the FileInputStream explicitly or by using try-with-resource blocks leads to java.io.IOException: Stream Closed, which I think happens because the stream is closed before the responseEntity can be returned.

Comment: You want something like `try (InputStreamResource resource = new InputStreamResource(Files.newInputStream(Path.of(filePath)))) {return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + filePath()).contentType(mediaType).contentLength(file.length()).body(resource);}` A little tweak might be necessary to putting the file name in the header

Comment: That’s not the responsibility of the GC but the *caller* which will process the `ResponseEntity`.